# Ubuntu 13.04 does not boot after I upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, radeon, windows-8

Ubuntu 13.04 doesn't boot up after I upgrade from 12.10. I have tried to edit the grub (nomodeset), but it still doesn't work.

I have a HP Pavilion dv6-2153eo PC and a ATI Radeon graphics card.

Comment: Does grub boot? Or Windows?

Comment: I have grub boot

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with a boot because I do believe that there are a few problems with the upgrade! There is a note to this affect in the docs. Also the graphics change again back to the stock solution.  So if you don't get an answer, you will have to do what I myself did in this situation. Admittedly I do have another Ubuntu 12.04 partition, but a Win7 partition might also work.

Get into the other partition and save all your /home/myname files somewhere safe on the other partition. Ensure that they have the correct ownership, i.e. "myname", or group me "myname". Now download the ISO for 13.04 and burn it to CD or DVD because the USB support is no longer [another note for that].

Install 13.04 all new onto the correct partition, with or without swap. Copy over any hidden home files etc as necessary. Good Luck!

Comment: Why you don't recommend installation using USB, it perfectly works, I installed 13.04 using USB.

Comment: There are some install notes for 13.04 which mention that most USB boot methods are no longer available. However it's great that you got it to work for yourself!

Comment: check this I got after I run the boot-repair dvd: paste2.org/cj0K8pbF

Comment: Looking at the bottom of the listing, it appears that your system is repaired - as far as booting is concerned.
If it works that's great, if it doesn't work then I suggest a reinstall from CD/DVD. You will have to specify which partitions you will be using on your system.